# SQL Query is multiplying from a JOIN

Tags: sql

I have a table with an ID #.  I want to count the rows in 2 other tables (one in another database) and display how many records each table has with that ID.
The 2 separate queries work, but when I combine them, the results are multiplied.
Here is my code:

```
The First Count works:
SELECT PRIMARY.dbo.MainTbl.FileIDRef, COUNT(PRIMARY.dbo.1stTbl.FileIDRef) AS 1stCnt
FROM PRIMARY.dbo.MainTbl
INNER JOIN PRIMARY.dbo.1stTbl ON PRIMARY.dbo.MainTbls.FileIDRef = PRIMARY.dbo.1stTbl.FileIDRef
GROUP BY PRIMARY.dbo.MainTbl.FileIDRef, PRIMARY.dbo.1stTbl.FileIDRef

Result
FileIDRef    1stCnt
2011         135

The 2nd count works:
SELECT PRIMARY.dbo.MainTbl.FileIDRef, COUNT(2NDARY.dbo.2ndTbl.FileIDRef) AS 2ndCnt
FROM PRIMARY.dbo.MainTbl
INNER JOIN 2NDARY.dbo.2ndTbl ON DB1.PRIMARY.MainTbls.FileIDRef = 2NDARY.dbo.2ndTbl.FileIDRef
GROUP BY PRIMARY.dbo.MainTbl.FileIDRef, 2NDARY.dbo.2ndTbl.FileIDRef

Result
FileIDRef    2ndCnt
2011         115

The Combined query gives a multiply of 1st and 2nd choice
SELECT PRIMARY.dbo.MainTbl.FileIDRef, COUNT(PRIMARY.dbo.1stTbl.FileIDRef) AS 1stCnt, 
COUNT(2NDARY.dbo.2ndTbl.FileIDRef) AS 2ndCnt
FROM PRIMARY.dbo.MainTbl
INNER JOIN PRIMARY.dbo.1stTbl ON PRIMARY.dbo.MainTbls.FileIDRef = PRIMARY.dbo.1stTbl.FileIDRef
INNER JOIN 2NDARY.dbo.2ndTbl ON DB1.PRIMARY.MainTbls.FileIDRef = 2NDARY.dbo.2ndTbl.FileIDRef
GROUP BY PRIMARY.dbo.MainTbl.FileIDRef, PRIMARY.dbo.1stTbl.FileIDRef, 2NDARY.dbo.2ndTbl.FileIDRef

Result
FileIDRef    1stCnt    2ndCnt
2011         18975     18975

Result Should be:
FileIDRef    1stCnt   2ndCnt
2011         135      115
```

What am I missing??

Comment: This may help. If table A has FileIDRef in it 4 times and table B has the same FileIDRef in it 6 times when you inner join them you will be joining 4 rows to 6 other rows and will get 4x6. Try joining using a primary key from one of the tables

Comment: You should join the aggregated queries... not the underlying tables ;)

Comment: Table A has only one row one column and the cell contains fileIDRef.  The other tables have FileIDRef column.  that is my matching criteria.  So if Table A has the PK FileIDRef as 2011, how many rows (count) of the other 2 tables have a FileIDRef of 2011?